# Is it possible to use 'enctype' and 'method'=post in JSP page..?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to take bulk datas from JSP.. So i have to use method="post".. At the same time i have to upload images using 'enctype'.. When i use both method="post" and 'enctype' then out of memory: heap size overflow message is coming.
I want to take bulk data along with image upload.. Is it possible..? How..? Plz answer my question ..

Answer (score 0):

Increase the heap size by setting `-Xmx` of the JVM

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to process `multipart/form-data` requests. It not only eases splitting and gathering uploaded files in the Servlet side, but it also allows for fine-grained memory configuration. Even more, the `DiskFileItemFactory` has a default threshold size of 10KB. The remnant will be written to disk.

For a short but complete example how to use it, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824).